# Jquery unable to change form value on form that is loaded

Tags: jquery, forms, field, hidden

I am new to JQuery and needed a decision tree for a site I'm making. I used a custom lightbox function to load the initial 'quiz' then, dependant on the answers to the 'quiz', a certain contact form loads in the same window. This is all OK and the form works fine. The problem is that I need to record the answers from the 'quiz'. I have managed to get JQuery to save the answers in a variable but I just can't get the value of my hidden input on the contact form to changed to the value of the variable.

To save posting ALL of the code, the quiz is generally a bunch of questions like the ones below that are set to show the next question when a user clicks the answer. I have the actual inputs hidden via CSS so the labels appear like buttons:

```
<div id="q1" class="question">
<h3 class="lightBlueText">Did you purchase your home privately or through the council's 'Right to Buy' scheme?</h3 class="lightBlueText">
<div id="a1" class="answer">
<div class="quizButton"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="private" value="Private" /> <label for="private" class="lblPrivate" id="category-private">Private</label></div>
<div class="quizButton"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="rtb" value="Right To Buy" /><label for="rtb" class="lblrtb" id="category-righttobuy">Right To Buy</label></div>
</div><!--answer1-->
</div><!--question1-->


<div id="q2a" class="question">
<h3 class="lightBlueText">Did you take out your mortgage within the last 7 years?</h3 class="lightBlueText">
<div id="a2a" class="answer">
<div class="quizButton"><input type="radio" name="q2a" id="p1" value="Yes" /><label for="p1" class="lblYes" id="q1-private-yes">Yes</label></div>
<div class="quizButton"><input type="radio" name="q2a" id="p2" value="No" /><label for="p2" class="gotoSorry" id="q1-private-no">No</label></div>
<div class="quizButton"><input type="radio" name="q2a" id="p3" value="Don't Know" /><label for="p3" class="lblYes" id="q1-private-dontknow">Don't Know</label></div>
</div><!--answer2-->
</div><!--question2-->

<!--more questions here-->

<div id="q5a" class="question">
<h3 class="lightBlueText">Did you use your mortgage/remortgage to consolidate your debts?</h3 class="lightBlueText">
<div id="a5a" class="answer">
<div class="quizButton"><input type="button" name="q5a" value="Yes" id="p10" /><label for="p10" class="gotoForm1" id="q4-private-yes">Yes</label></div>
<div class="quizButton"><input type="button" name="q5a" value="No" id="p11"/><label for="p11" class="gotoSorry" id="q4-private-no">No</label></div>
<div class="quizButton"><input type="button" name="q5a" value="Don't Know" id="p12" /><label for="p12" class="gotoForm2" id="q4-private-dontknow">Don't Know</label></div>
</div><!--answer5-->
</div><!--question5-->
```

the Jquery (forgive my novice code):

```
    var id;
var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/test/sapphire';
var quiz_answers;
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.question').hide();//hide all
   $('#q1').show();//show the first question
   quiz_answers = "Answers: "; //reset quiz answers
    $('.quizButton label').click(function()
        {
        //get the id of what was just clicked.
        //This is the value of the radio button that we need to select
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        //as long as clickable text is in a tag that
        //has a class of ‘quizButton’ and an id with the value of the
        //radio button that it needs to select, we only need this statement.
        $('input[value=" + id + "]').attr("checked", true);

        if ($(this).is('.lblrtb')){ //this is to jump to the Right to Buy section and bypass the Private section
                $('.question:visible:first').fadeOut(function(){
                $('#q2b').fadeIn(); });
        }
        else { //else it will carry on through the Private section
                $('.question:visible:first').fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).next('.question:hidden').fadeIn('slow');
                                                              });
        }
        quiz_answers = quiz_answers + " " + id; //add the id of clicked label onto the variable 
    });


    $('.gotoForm1').click(function(){
        change_form(); 
        $('#msm-form_wrapper').load(root+'/msm_form1.php');//open the contact form
        $('input[name="answers"]').val(quiz_answers);
        });

    $('.gotoForm2').click(function(){
        change_form();
        $("#msm-form_wrapper").load(root+'/msm_form2.php');//open the contact form
        $('input[name="answers"]').val(quiz_answers);
       });

    $('.gotoSorry').click(function(){
        change_form();
        $("#msm-form_wrapper").load(root+'/sorry.php');//open the contact form
        $('input[name="answers"]').val(quiz_answers);
       });


function change_form() {
    $('#quiz_wrapper').hide();
    $('#msm-form_wrapper').show();
};

$('.close, .backdrop').click(function(){
    quiz_answers = "Answers: "; //reset quiz_answers if the user closes the contact form before submitting
});
```

And finally an example of what is contained in the loaded files:

```
<form id="msm_form1" method="POST" action="/test/sapphire/contact-form-handler.php" class="msm_form">
<h1>Sorry...</h1>
<p class="sorry">It's unlikely that we can help you this time, however if you would like someone to call you back please fill in the form below.</p>
    <fieldset class="plain sorry">
        <ul>
            <li><label for='firstname'>First Name:</label><input type="text" name="firstname" id="input-firstname"></li>
            <li><label for='lastname'>Last Name:</label><input type="text" name="lastname"></li>
            <li><label for='contact'>Contact Number:</label><input type="text" name="contact"></li>
            <li><label for='email'>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email"></li>
            <li><label for='comments' class="comments">Comments:</label><textarea name="comments"></textarea></li>
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="Sorry Form" />
            <input type="hidden" name="answers" value="" />
            <li class="submit-label">Send your message<button type="submit" class="msm-form-submit"></button></li>
        </ul>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I can use alert('quiz_answers'); at any stage and get the correct result, it just wont put that result into the form.

I have tried various methods like adding an ID to the input named 'answers' and then using  $('#answers').val(quiz_answers);

but that didnt work either. In testing I was unable to get anything added to any of the form inputs and I think it might be due to the way I load the extra content into the div. Changing that method If anyone has any suggestions I would be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the value you're trying to set the hidden field  <input type="hidden" name="answers" value="" /> ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set `<input type="hidden" name="answers" value="" />` then using `$('#answers').val(quiz_answers);` won't work since you have no id defined for this field.

You can try doing one of the following:

```
<input type="hidden" id="answersVal" name="answers" value="" />
```

and then using `$('#answersVal').val(quiz_answers);`

Or:

```
    <input type="hidden" class="answersVal" name="answers" value="" />
```

and then using `$('.answersVal').val(quiz_answers);`

Comment: As I said in the original post, I've tried setting an ID on the input and that doesn't work. I've just tried using class and that doesn't work either. It doesn't work when trying set any value on any input in the form. I tried a little test and added var getAttrTest = $('.quiz-answers').attr('id');        alert(getAttrTest); to the click function and it returns "undefined" even though I set the class on one of the form inputs and also set an id.

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet, but I got around it by adding a line of script to the top of the document that is inserted by the quiz script above. Not sure why it doesnt work in the original script but $('.quiz-answers').val(quiz_answers); works when it is in the inserted document.